# How do I prevent the cancel event from changing my grid row color?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I search for data and then bind to my grid. In the grid's `databound` event, I change the row background color according to the cell's value. This works OK. But when I click the Edit button in the grid and then click the Cancel button, the grid no longer has the background color set. I tried to call the `databound` event in the `Cancel` event, but it does not work. How do I prevent the Cancel Event from changing my grid color?

**grid**

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) 
            .Name("mygrid")
             .Events(e=>e.DataBound("dataBound"))
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
            columns.Bound(p =>p.StudentName).Title("StudentName");
            columns.Command(command =>
             {
              command.Edit().UpdateText("Edit");
              command.Destroy().Text("Delete");
             }).Width(160);
                })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
            .TemplateName("SudentEditor")
            .Window(configurator=>configurator.Width(500)
            .Title("EditStudent")))
            .Scrollable() 
            .Events(events=>events.Cancel("onCancel"))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                    model.Id(p => p.Id);
                    })
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetStudentForGrid", "Student"))
                .Create(create=>create.Action("CreateSudent","Equipment"))        
                .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateStudent", "Student"))
                .Destroy(destory=>destory.Action("DestroyStudent","Student"))     
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            ))
```

**databound event**

```
  //change grid color
   function dataBound(e) {

        $("#mygrid tbody tr").each(function(i) {
          $(this).find("td:lt(9)").css("backgroundColor", '#000000');
        });
    }
```

**cancel event**

```
     //I try to call preventDefault event and close the PopUp window
    //,but the background is still grey
    function onCancel(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.container.parent().css("display", "none");
   // e.sender.clearSelection();
    dataBound();
}
```

Comment: Hello Lyly, I have edited your question title to better reflect what you are asking. If you feel it is wrong, feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: Also, you might possibly have an error here: `=>destory.Action(...` (destroy is spelt wrong).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `grid.cancelRow()` in the `cancel enent`,and then refresh the grid.

Answer (score 7):

Just refresh the grid in the cancel event. It will fire the onDataBound event again. I had the same issue and resolved it like this:

```
function onCancel(e) {

   $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").refresh();

}

//change grid color
function dataBound(e) {

    $("#mygrid tbody tr").each(function(i) {
        $(this).find("td:lt(9)").css("backgroundColor", '#000000');
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry mate wrong code. it should be  $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").refresh();

Comment: This partially works in that it successfully calls the databound event again but its persists (client side) changes that were made to cells within the row.
Solved one problem but created another.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refresh the grid but run code after the event has finished instead, you can use a setTimeout() in the cancel event.

```
function onGridCancel(e){
  setTimeout(function() {
    colorMyRowsBeutifully();
  }, 0);
}
```

See this answer from Telerik:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-cancel-event

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and the solutions from above didn't work for me.
But I found another solution that did the trick, to use  the Edit event of the Grid to attach event handler to the Deactivate event of the Window.

Grid events:

```
.Events(e => {
    e.DataBound("onDataBound");
    e.Edit("onEdit");
})
```

Grid event handlers:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    //Conditional formatting on DataBound
    formatGridRows();
}


function onEdit(e) {
    //Bind deactivate event to the Popup window
    e.container.data("kendoWindow").bind("deactivate", function () {
        formatGridRows();
    })
}

function formatGridRows() {
    $("#Grid tbody tr").each(function () {
        grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));

        //Conditionally format the current row
        if (dataItem.Discontinued) {
            $(this).find(":nth-child(3):first").css("background", "red");
        }
    })
}
```

Here's the source:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/cancel-popup-clears-grid-background-color